# MongoDB Mongoose findById always returns null

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

The object I'm trying to retrieve

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"62cc01ae2e97ca440410b897"},
    "photo":"https://picsum.photos/300",
    "userId":{"$oid":"62c9688c3663450fd0d4cf4b"},
    "title":"Small Cod","body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "stock":"12",
    "price":"8.99",
    "diet":"",
    "type":"Fish",
    "createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1657536942137"}},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}
}
```

The body of my get request with the itemId

```
{
    "userId": "62cbe1d13e967917d0847579",
    "items": [{
        "itemId": "62cc01ae2e97ca440410b897",
        "qty": "2"
    }],
    "destination": "74 Seabury Lawns Mornington Meath",
    "type": "delivery",
    "payment": "card"
}
```

The route

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { items } = req.body;

  const orderItem = await Item.findById(
    mongoose.Types.ObjectId(items[1].itemId)
  );

  res.json(orderItem);
});
```

The result

[image]

I assume it's a data type issue because when I replace the variable with the string "62cc01ae2e97ca440410b897" everything works fine. Been going back an forth between converting to string and to object and nothing seems to work.

Comment: `items[1]` - this might be an issue.

Comment: That's an error no my part supposed to be items[0]. With this results are the same.

Comment: No actually, that fixed it. 4h of my life ill never get back. Thank you!